# How to negate this compound statement?

Tags: calculus, logic

[image: Statement is underlined by red]

I understand that we can negate the quantifiers, but what about the inequalities and implications? This is what I have so far.

[image]

Comment: I don't know...  what is not less than equivalent to ?

Comment: i would say greater than  ... so that's it?

Comment: it's actually greater than or equal to with MathJax that's $\geq$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)  may help you

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think Juma is trying to negate the statement, not the inequalities.  That is, the question is asking whether the inequalities and implications should be flipped.

Comment: please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negating a statement means saying that the statement is false.  So, if $P$ is a statement, its negation $\neg P$ should mean the same thing as "$P$ is false."

For example, what is the negation of $\forall x P(x)$?  This statement currently says "for all $x$, $P(x)$ is true".  Claiming that this is false is saying that there is a counterexample; that is: $\exists x \neg P(x).$

Similarly, $\exists x P(x)$ is saying "there exists $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true".  Then its negation is that no such $x$ exists; that is, $\nexists x P(x)$.  Or equivalently, $\forall x \neg P(x)$ (why is this equivalent?).

Finally, to get to the part you are asking about, what are the negations of $P\rightarrow Q$ and $A<B$, and should we use them?

$P\rightarrow Q$ says "if $P$ is true, $Q$ is also true."  So $\neg P\rightarrow Q$ says that this is false: $P\land\lnot Q$.

Finally, as Roddy MacPhee mentioned in the comments, "not $A<B$" means the same thing as $A\ge B$ (as long as we are working over the real numbers, or any other set with a total order.)

In your case, you want to negate

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{Z},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\rightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon;$$

that is, you want to find a statement equivalent to

$$\neg(\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{Z},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\rightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon)$$

(and I assume you want to do this without using the word "not", or else you could just leave it this way). The first bit is saying that, for all $\epsilon>0$, [some condition] holds.  From earlier, we can negate this by saying that there exists a counterexample:

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\neg(\exists N\in\mathbb{Z},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\rightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon).$$

We can now negate the existence as

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\neg(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\rightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon).$$

Negating the "for all" statement gives

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}, \neg(n>N\rightarrow L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon).$$

To negate the implication,

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\land \neg(L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon).$$

Now, $L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon$ really means $L-\epsilon<a_n\land a_n<L+\epsilon$, so what is left to remove the word "not" from is

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\land \neg(L-\epsilon<a_n\land a_n<L+\epsilon).$$

When is $A\land B$ false? When at least one of them is false. So this is equivalent to

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\land \neg(L-\epsilon<a_n) \lor \neg(a_n<L+\epsilon)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb{Z},\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>N\land L-\epsilon\ge a_n \lor a_n\ge L+\epsilon.$$

Comment: how come you don't change the inequalities?

Comment: @Juma: I presume your asking about the non-change of $n>N$, since the other inequalities do change in the last step. The reason that $n>N$ doesn't change is because it's at the start of an implication - i.e. something of the form $P \implies Q$ - and we have to negate that first. We demonstrate that an implication $P \implies Q$ is false by showing that $P$ is true but that it failed to imply $Q$ as $Q$ is false (if you're unsure about this, there are plenty of other questions on the site about it). So the final statement still has something to the effect that $P$ is true: i.e that $n>N$.

Comment: @Chessanator I'm talking about the epsilon > 0 at the beginning. Shoudln't it be less than or equal to zero after the negation?

Comment: @Juma Consider the statement "For all x>0, [some claim about x] is true".  The negation is that there exists a counterexample.  If we came up with some negative value of x such that the claim were false, that would not be a counterexample to the statement; that is, a counterexample is an example of a positive number such that the claim is false.